# How should I pass user credentials from one services to a second one?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, active-directory, credentials

I would like to move some generic type functionality out of some of my apps into a central api that I can make requests to. I am having problems with a specific case however where I have some functions based around the user and AD.

The users credentials are passed to the first application fine however the second application is passed the user that the app pool is running as.

Firstly having tried to research this question am I approaching the problem in a sensible way? Should I continue trying to get the two API's to talk to each other or should I be using the client as a go between?

If I am approaching this in a sensible way what is the best way forward? searching Google and here has given me varying ways I could approach this (Kerberos, impersonation) but it isn't clear (to me at least) which is the best route to take?

Thanks in advance.

**[UPDATE]**

Some more details on how I pass the details in case this helps with the problem.

```
try
{
    using (var client = new WebClient { UseDefaultCredentials = true })
    {
        string request = BuildRequest();
        string response = client.DownloadString(request);
        return Convert.ToBoolean(response);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return false;
}
```

The above as mentioned before makes the second api call fine however the user credentials that are passed are not the user calling the first API but are the credentials of the user the App Pool is running as.

Comment: I think you may want to implement SSO with AD FS 2.0 (Active Directory Federation Services). I have no experience with it myself, so it is just a thought.

Comment: Thanks for that and it is something extra to look into however I am hoping for some guidance towards the correct path with an answer. I will continue looking into this but any help with what is the correct path for my efforts would be appreciated.